# How could I transform a datetime dataframe column to int64, replacing the value 2018-08-01 to 20180801?

Tags: python, dataframe

How could I transform a datetime dataframe column to int64, replacing the value 2018-08-01 to 20180801?

```
  myDataFrame

  DATA_REFE COD_SGTO 

0 2018-08-01        1
1 2018-08-01        1
2 2018-08-01        1
3 2018-08-01        1
4 2018-08-01        1

myDataFrame column type
DATA_REFE       datetime64[ns]
COD_SGTO                object

df['DATA_REFE'].astype(str).replace('-', '')
```

The result continue the same

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? What is your end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myDataFrame['DATA_REFE'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code with `str.replace` and extra `astype`:

```
df['DATA_REFE'] = df['DATA_REFE'].astype(str).str.replace('-', '').astype(int)
```